# Having difficulty with xpath function text()

Tags: typescript, playwright

I wrote a really simple test, navigate to a page after logging in, and clicking an element once the page is loaded

In my selenium project I use the xpath text() function to help me look for specific icons in the app im automating

I was wondering how to do that with playwright

here is my test, it uses the page object modal in the playwright documentation

```
test('Navigate using POM', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('/db');
  const mainView = new MainView(page);
  mainView.selectSampleInSideNav();
});
```

the problem is the icon I need to click on is defined by a specific text in the HTML, but that exact text is used on another element so I cannot write something like(also it has the white spaces in the html as well)

```
await page.click('text= Sample ');
```

Is there a way to write this xpath expression in playwright?

```
"//mat-icon[text()=' Sample ']"
```

I've tried something like this:

```
const sideNavSample =  page.$('mat-icon >> text=" Sample "');
```

but i get a Cannot read property of 'click' of undefined when i try to interact with sideNavSample

```
await this.sideNavSample.click();
```

Any help would be wonderful, as Xpath is the only way I can define a unique identifier for this specific icon.
Apologies if this is a dumb question

@archon thank you for the suggestion but it seems that when I write out the click action exactly the way you have it written it works just fine, but when I store it in a variable it fails.
I cant explain why but
this works
`page.click('//mat-icon[contains(text(), "Sample")]')`

this does not
`this.sampleOptionInSideNav =  page.locator('//mat-icon[contains(text(), " Sample ")]');`
`await this.reviewOptionInSideNav.click();`

Comment: I think the issue might be the whitespace. `text()='x'` pattern looks for an exact text match. You can try `page.click('//mat-icon[contains(text(), "Sample")]')`.

Comment: Well i need to include the whitespace otherwise it wouldnt be an exact match but your solution using contains() worked

Comment: For strict matching, you can try using `text-is`, and for selecting `mat-icon` with strict text rules, this `page.locator('mat-icon :text-is(" Sample ")');` might work

Comment: thank you @archon i just had to put await before the calling function and it worked. I appreciate your insight and help typescript is very new to me

Comment: @archon do you want to put that in an answer?

Comment: Oh I should. I've posted the first 2 comments of mine as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()='x'` pattern looks for an exact text match. You can try `page.click('//mat-icon[contains(text(), "Sample")]')`.

For strict matching, you should use `text-is`, and for selecting `mat-icon` with strict text rules, this `await page.locator('mat-icon :text-is(" Sample ")')` can work.